# Xamarin.Forms Customize NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.Forms cross-platform(Android and IOS) i need to customize my navigationPage. Need Title to be center. Something like this example:

[image]

Am i need to create stacklayout organize in custom renderer and import it?

Comment: you need to have custom renderer for sure. No other trick to make title at center.

Comment: You can use a custom renderer or TitleView.
There are _lots_ of examples on how to do this.

Comment: I think customize the titleView is enough to meet your requirement. Here is the code example:     <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Images" 
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Label Text="title" 
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Image Source="Images"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" /> </StackLayout> </NavigationPage.TitleView>

Comment: But how to make one titleview for every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Xamarin.Forms.TitleView`to customize it and make it according to your design requirement.

Please refer this example here: [using TitleView to customize navigation bar](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TitleView)

Comment: TitleView is working for IOS?

Comment: Yes, Its working for that as well

Comment: I'm truing to make custom renderer on every page. Is there any solution?

Comment: Example for custom rendered for navigation?